# Number of Paths in a Graph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I have an undirected, unweighted graph. Let us fix a vertex and find all distinct paths from that vertex which covers all vertices of the graph. The task is to find the number of possible such paths from every vertices. 
 Eg: Let us take a graph of **4 vertices** `[ 1, 2, 3, 4]`. And the **edges** are (1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,2). Here **answer** is **4**. The paths are `1>2>3>4`, `1>2>4>3`, `3>4>2>1`, `4>3>2>1`.

---

I have come with an algorithm which uses brute-force technique to find the number of possible such paths, initialized by each vertex.
Eg:
For the above example: 
`From vertex 1 there is 2 such path;` 
`From vertex 2 there is no such path;` 
`From vertex 3 there is 1 such path;` 
`From vertex 4 there is 1 such path;` 
So the **answer** is **2+1+1=4**.

---

Is it possible to solve this problem in a better *time complexity?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deciding if a graph $G$ has a Hamiltonian Circuit is $NP$-Hard. Enumerating those Hamiltonian circuits is therefore computationally difficult. You are unlikely to find a solution in reasonable time complexity.